# sql timestamp can't show correct timeago

Tags: php, mysql

i make a post in my website and want to show time stemp as "3 min ago"
but this is my function which is not working correctly.

mysql `timestamp` on post update passed as `$time` like `2018-04-15 09:00:02`
this post make time is only just some mints ago but Result on page after function process this shows `9 Hours ago`
Please Help Me to show Correct TimeAgo

```
public static function timeago($time){
   $time=strtotime($time);
   $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
   $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
   $now = time();
     $difference = $now - $time;
     $tense= "ago";
     for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
       $difference /= $lengths[$j];
     }
     $difference = round($difference);
     if($difference != 1) {
       $periods[$j].= "s";
     }
   return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense ";
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to debug this yourself? If I were you, I'd start by watching the value of `$difference`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you didn't write a statement for a timestamp value,
I mean that every value you used in the function is considered as a timestamp and not time string.

```
public static function timeago($time){
    if (!is_numeric($time) || (int)$time != $time)
        $time=strtotime($time);
    $periods = array("second", "minute", "hour", "day", "week", "month", "year", "decade");
    $lengths = array("60","60","24","7","4.35","12","10");
    $now = time();
    $difference = $now - $time;
    $tense= "ago";
    for($j = 0; $difference >= $lengths[$j] && $j < count($lengths)-1; $j++) {
        $difference /= $lengths[$j];
    }
    $difference = round($difference);
    if($difference != 1) {
        $periods[$j].= "s";
    }
   return "$difference $periods[$j] $tense ";
}
```

BTW, I'm sorry for my English, this is not my native language.

Comment: Thanks Man Its Woks for me. but it show seconds like ``10432 seconds ago`` can you please update me to convert in minuts

Comment: It works for me as timestmap and as time string, can you give me the timestamp or time string that you try to convert?

Comment: database timestamp ``2018-04-15 09:00:02`` please help me to parse in minuts

Comment: Well, I check it just now and you right. I solve the problem with date_default_timezone_set. This is happening because of the date we are put in function is bigger from server time.

Comment: Please See this Output screenshoot http://www.auplod.com/u/alopuda78b9.jpeg its not working fine somewhere it show seconds and now its do wrong things  please help me

Comment: @MAbidMajeed (https://prnt.sc/j61mz8) as you can see it works, we use the same code. the only thing is a difference between us is our time server. check it out.

Comment: Please help me to update servver time configuration it gose to minus -ve time not in "1 sec ago" :( please tell me about server time change